# sql group the values if they are the same

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion

i wrote a sql-server code and coldfusion table, with products and prices, each product have 5 different prices and all the prices are displayed correctly while they are different from each other, but if the products 5 prices are the same, they are grouped as one. anyway hope everything will be clear from code and screenshot.

**here is the sql:**

```
SELECT P.PRODUCT_ID,
       P.PRODUCT_NAME,
       PS.MONEY,
       PR.PRICE,
       P.BRAND_ID,
       PS.PRICE,
       GSL.PRODUCT_STOCK,
       GSL.PURCHASE_ORDER_STOCK,
       GSL.SALEABLE_STOCK,
       P.PRODUCT_DETAIL2,
       P.BARCOD
FROM PRODUCT P
JOIN PRICE_STANDART PS ON P.PRODUCT_ID = PS.PRODUCT_ID
JOIN PRICE PR ON P.PRODUCT_ID = PR.PRODUCT_ID
JOIN #DSN2_ALIAS#.GET_STOCK_LAST GSL ON P.PRODUCT_ID = GSL.PRODUCT_ID
WHERE PS.PURCHASESALES=1 AND 
      PS.PRICESTANDART_STATUS=1 AND
      P.IS_SALES=1 AND
      P.IS_INTERNET=1 AND
      P.IS_EXTRANET=1
GROUP BY 
      P.PRODUCT_ID,
      PR.PRICE,
      P.PRODUCT_NAME,
      PS.MONEY,
      P.BRAND_ID,
      PS.PRICE,
      GSL.PRODUCT_STOCK,
      GSL.PURCHASE_ORDER_STOCK,
      GSL.SALEABLE_STOCK,
      P.PRODUCT_DETAIL2,
      P.BARCOD
ORDER BY
    P.PRODUCT_ID, PR.PRICE DESC
```

**and the table:**

```
<tr class="color-header">
        <td width="170"><b>Ürün</b></td>
        <td class="header_bold"><b>Açıklama 2</b></td>
        <td class="header_bold" width="100"><b>Marka</b></td>
        <cfif isdefined('attributes.department_id') and len(attributes.department_id)>
        <td class="header_bold" width="35"><b>Depo Stok</b></td>
        <cfelse>
            <td class="header_bold" width="35"><b>Stok</b></td>
            <td class="header_bold" width="50"><b>Satabilen Stok</b></td>
            <td class="header_bold" width="35"><b>Yoldaki Stok</b></td>
        </cfif>
        <cfif (session.ep.admin is 1) or (session.ep.userid is 19)>
            <td class="header_bold" width="70">Dön. Sonu B.Maliyet $</td>
        </cfif>
        <td class="header_bold" width="90">Liste Fiatı</td>
        <td class="header_bold" <cfif isdefined('get_company.companycat_id') and len(get_company.companycat_id) and (get_company.companycat_id eq 6)>style="color:yellow;font-size:9pt;background:#000;"</cfif> width="80">Bayi 1</td>
        <td class="header_bold" <cfif isdefined('get_company.companycat_id') and len(get_company.companycat_id) and (get_company.companycat_id eq 7)>style="color:yellow;font-size:9pt;background:#000;"</cfif> width="80">Bayi 2 <br /> 12 Ay 0 faiz</td>
        <td class="header_bold" <cfif isdefined('get_company.companycat_id') and len(get_company.companycat_id) and (get_company.companycat_id eq 8)>style="color:yellow;font-size:9pt;background:#000;"</cfif> width="80">Bayi 3 <br /> 30-60-90 çek</td>
        <td class="header_bold" <cfif isdefined('get_company.companycat_id') and len(get_company.companycat_id) and (get_company.companycat_id eq 9)>style="color:yellow;font-size:9pt;background:#000;"</cfif> width="80">Bayi 4 Tek Çekim Peşin</td>
        <cfif (session.ep.admin is 1) or (session.ep.userid is 19)>
        <td class="header_bold" width="60">
            <cfif isdefined('attributes.yoldaki_stock') and attributes.yoldaki_stock is 1>
                Yoldaki
            <cfelseif isdefined('attributes.department_id') and len(attributes.department_id)>
                Depodaki
            <cfelse>
                Satabilen
            </cfif>Hesapla
        </td>
        </cfif>
        <td class="header_bold" width="25">Para</td>
    </tr>

    <cfoutput query="get_products" startrow="#attributes.startrow#" maxrows="#attributes.maxrows#" group="product_id">
            <cfquery name="get_maliyet" datasource="#dsn3#">SELECT PURCHASE_NET_SYSTEM_MONEY,(PURCHASE_NET_SYSTEM+PURCHASE_EXTRA_COST_SYSTEM) AS DS_MALIYET FROM PRODUCT_COST WHERE PRODUCT_ID=#PRODUCT_ID#</cfquery><cfif len(get_maliyet.ds_maliyet)><cfset toplam_maliyet=get_maliyet.ds_maliyet+toplam_maliyet></cfif>
            <tr height="20" onMouseOver="this.className='color-light';" onMouseOut="this.className='color-row';" class="color-row"> 
                <td>
                    <a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=product.form_upd_product&pid=#product_id#" style="color:blue;" target="_blank">#left(product_name,25)#</a>
                </td>
                <td>#left(PRODUCT_DETAIL2,45)#</td>
                <td align="center"><cfif len(brand_list)>#get_brands.brand_name\[listfind(brand_list,brand_id,',')\]#</cfif></td>
                <cfif isdefined('attributes.department_id') and len(attributes.department_id)>
                    <td align="center">#product_stock2#</td>
                <cfelse>
                    <td align="center">#PRODUCT_STOCK#</td>
                    <td align="center">#saleable_stock#</td>
                    <td align="center">#purchase_order_stock#</td>
                </cfif>
                <cfif (session.ep.admin is 1) or (session.ep.userid is 19)>
                    <td align="center"><cfif len(GET_MALIYET.DS_MALIYET)>#tlformat(GET_MALIYET.DS_MALIYET/get_money.rate2,2)#<cfelse>0</cfif></td>
                </cfif>
                <cfoutput>
                    <td align="center">#tlformat(price,2)#</td>
                </cfoutput>
            <cfif (session.ep.admin is 1) or (session.ep.userid is 19)>
                <td align="center"><a href="javascript://" onclick="gizle_goster(abr#currentrow#);" style="font-weight:bold;"><cfif isdefined('attributes.yoldaki_stock') and attributes.yoldaki_stock is 1>x #purchase_order_stock#<cfelseif isdefined('attributes.department_id') and len(attributes.department_id)>x #product_stock2#<cfelse>x #saleable_stock#</cfif></a></td>
            </cfif>
            <td align="center">#MONEY#</td>
        </tr>
</cfoutput>
```

on screenshot u can quickly learn and understand the problem. ofcourse i edited a little bit the code and erased unnecessary parts. Everyone, thank you for help! ^^

[image: clearifying screenshot]

Comment: That's XML - not SQL.  Please present SQL!  Or tag with XML.  But that is definitely not readable.

Comment: @Jonathan this is not xml! this is sql man

Comment: What happens if you remove the `group by` clause?.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson the products will be rearranged and repeated due to different prices, for each product there will be 4 more rows or maybe more i dont remeber exacty

Comment: the problem part here is this: `<cfoutput><td align="center">#tlformat(price,2)#</td></cfoutput>` one output is inside another

Comment: What happens if you remove `group by price` like `GROUP BY P.PRODUCT_ID,  P.PRODUCT_NAME,PS.MONEY,P.BRAND_ID,PS.PRICE,GSL.PRODUCT_STOCK,GSL.PURCHASE_ORDER_STOCK,GSL.SALEABLE_STOCK,P.PRODUCT_DETAIL2,P.BARCOD`

Comment: You are doing a group by on **all** columns. That is the same as doing a `select distinct ...`. If your current query does not give you enough rows because of the same value in a price column you need to include some other column that will make the row distinct from other rows.  You say you have five prices, perhaps there are a PriceType column number 1-5 or something like that.

Comment: @Pikaurd nothing's changed, once i replace it, but once i remove it, the mistake comes out

Comment: thanks for the advice! :) but still didnt understand how to include some other column, that will make the row distinct from other rows?!

Comment: The problem is "generated html has something wrong", but sql is correct. Right?

Comment: @Pikaurd yes, but if i erase the `pr.price`, there comes one price for each product

Comment: YES! I've solved it! thank you all for the help! i removed all the group clauses )) that was the solution ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your SQL query, you're grouping on the price field so it's collapsing those records down into one before it returns the results to ColdFusion.  Remove the price column from the GROUP BY clause of the query and this should be corrected.